# Using the Terminal

Tags: dual-boot, mount, fstab

How critical are spaces when inputting instructions in the terminal?
I have a new laptop dual-booting Ubuntu 19.10 and Win10 from an SSD and an HDD (NTFS) for storage.  I am following the instructions from The HOW-TO-GEEK titled "How to Harmonize Your Your Dual-Boot Setup" and got as far as this line:

```
# storage mount
UUID=66E53AEC54455DB2 /media/storage/    ntfs-3g        auto,user,rw 0 0
```

(used my UUID instead of this sample but the rest is as I inputted the instruction)
After a couple of days, I attempted to continue where I left off. I entered:
`gedit admin:///etc/fstab`
and got `Warning 10:49:38:637:
The specified location is not mounted`
I wondered if this warning was the result of incorrect spaces in the instruction I typed. FYI: the Fast Start Up in Win10 has been unselected

Comment: This warning doesn't seem related to mounting of a partition. The line in `fstab` looks correct. Can you reach your files on `/media/storage/`?

Comment: And how is the title of your question related to the question? You are not asking anything about terminal.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. Using the terminal is intimidating for a newbie so the question about spaces left in the typed instructions just reflects how little I know about how critical the spaces are in the command itself. I try to use copy and paste when possible to avoid that issue but this time I was reading from one laptop and writing to another. As for the first comment, using the Home screen, Other Locations, I can get to the single partition Data drive. What I'm trying to do is link Documents, Music, Pictures from Home to access the 1 TB Data single partition NTFS drive and not the SSD drive

Comment: Looked again and saw /media/storage and within it (i.e. storage) was the Data HDD with some folders I had placed there. But there is also /media/ted (empty so far) and /home/ted with all the folders I want to use i.e. Documents, Pictures, etc. If I'm understanding this correctly, both /home and /media are on the SSD whereas I want to store my data (from any of the folders on the Home screen menu) on the HDD data disk without having to go through the "Other Locations" option on the Home screen menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command lines in `bash` in the terminal window and many (but not all) configuration files can have one or more spaces between the items on the lines. The read process will treat several space characters in a row as one space character.

This is the case with the configuration file `/etc/fstab`, so you can add spaces (for example to align columns) in order to make it easier to read for the human eye.

Comment: Your answer was what I needed to know. Can I assume the number of spaces is not critical in any command?

Comment: In command lines, yes, because it will be interpreted by the shell. The standard shell in Ubuntu is `bash`.  But it can be different in some configuration files, that are interpreted by the particular program to which they belong.

Answer (score 1):

If your current method of editing the file is failing. You can try using:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

This method may work or at the very least you will get a different error message which will shed more light on why you can't edit the file with the current method.